# How to apply a Systemd change in the log level, after modifying the systemd configuration file?

Tags: systemd, logs, syslog

How do I apply a Systemd change in the log level (from `info` to `notice`), after I've modified the related file `/etc/systemd/system.conf`?

I didn't find the information in the `systemd-system.conf` manpage, and I'm wondering if I should:

- reload the Systemd configuration in some way (and how),
- or if I need to reboot the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemctl daemon-reexec` [should be enough](https://serverfault.com/questions/805745/reboot-or-systemctl-daemon-reload-for-changes-to-etc-systemd-system-conf),
but restart is always the most reliable option IMHO.